# Programmatically created view not working properly applied rule

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a custom dialog class with two images.

This is my class :

```
class TransparentProgressDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme) {
    private val iv_logo: ImageView
    private val iv: ImageView

    init {
        val wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes()

        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
        getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp)
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setTitle(null)
        setCancelable(false)
        setOnCancelListener(null)
        val rl = RelativeLayout(this.context)
        val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        params.height = 200
        params.width = 240

        iv = ImageView(context)
        iv.setId(View.generateViewId());
        iv_logo = ImageView(context)
        iv_logo.setId(View.generateViewId());

        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.app_logo_ic).into(iv_logo);
        Glide.with(context).asGif().load(R.raw.loading_gif).into(iv);

        rl.addView(iv_logo, params)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iv_logo.getId());

        rl.layoutParams = params
        rl.addView(iv, params)
        addContentView(rl, params)
    }

    override fun show() {
        super.show()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the added views are not showing below each other instead they appear on top of each other like this:

[image]

This is my style config in style file (DialogTheme) :

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>-->
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>-->
</style>
```

Bonus question: Can I achieve the same with an XML resource?

Comment: probably you need to set rules **before** adding view to layout?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks for respond . even after i moved both line "addRule" and "rl.layoutParams = params" before adding view still both layer stuck on top of each other.

Comment: then try to use different instances of layoutparams. Probably using same instance makes a conflict.